# Why do the Gospels not mention the name of Enoch?

Tags: catholicism, gospels, enoch

I use the NRSVCE of the Bible.

We read in Gen 5:24 :

> Enoch walked with God; then he was no more, because God took him

We also read in Heb 11:5 :

> By faith Enoch was taken so that he did not experience death, and “he was not found, because God had taken him.” For it was attested before he was taken away that “he had pleased God.”

Now, the name of Elijah, who was also spared from  death, appears in the Gospels a number of times. But, neither Jesus nor the Evangelists mention the name of Enoch, nor project him as a role mode of righteousness.

My question therefore is: **According to Catholic scholars, why do the Gospels not mention the name of Enoch?**

Comment: Why should they? There are lots of OT people they don't mention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why do the Gospels not mention the name of Enoch?**

Sorry to disappoint you, but it seems to me that the name of Enoch is mentioned in the Gospel of Luke.

> Who was of Mathusale, who was of **Henoch**, who was of Jared, who was of Malaleel, who was of Cainan. - [Luke 3:37](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%203&version=DRA)

He is mentioned two other times in the New Testament.

> The second mention is in the Epistle to the Hebrews which says, "By faith Enoch was translated that he should not see death; and was not found, because God had translated him: for before his translation he had this testimony, that he pleased God." (Hebrews 11:5 KJV). This suggests he did not experience the mortal death ascribed to Adam's other descendants, which is consistent with Genesis 5:24 KJV, which says, "And Enoch walked with God: and he [was] not; for God took him."
>
> The third mention is in the Epistle of Jude (1:14–15) where the author attributes to "Enoch, the Seventh from Adam" a passage not found in Catholic and Protestant canons of the Old Testament. The quotation is believed by most modern scholars to be taken from 1 Enoch 1:9 which exists in Greek, in Ge'ez (as part of the Ethiopian Orthodox canon), and also in Aramaic among the Dead Sea Scrolls. Though the same scholars recognise that 1 Enoch 1:9 itself is a midrash of Deuteronomy 33:2. - [Enoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enoch)

Answer (score 2):

We can't know why that decision was made. John in his gospel said that "Jesus did many other things as well. If every one of them were written down, I suppose that even the whole world would not have room for the books that would be written." Thus the writers had to be selective. The OT has over 3,000 people mentioned! The NT does not refer to them all!

John told his audience,

> Many have undertaken to draw up an account of the things that have
> been fulfilled among us, 2 just as they were handed down to us by
> those who from the first were eyewitnesses and servants of the word. 3
> With this in mind, since I myself have carefully investigated
> everything from the beginning, I too decided to write an orderly
> account for you, most excellent Theophilus, 4 so that you may know the
> certainty of the things you have been taught.

The other gospel writers all had goals, their own and the Holy Spirit's working in harmony. Enoch must not have satisfied those goals.

The Gospels tell us about Jesus first, other people second. What was important about Jesus?

- King in the line of David - way after Enoch
- Priest - the Jewish priesthood was setup long after Enoch
- Prophet
- seed of Eve (mentioned) a messianic promise
- like Noah, one who would save the earth
- one to fulfill the promises made to Abraham

If you consider the many messianic prophecies and promises that Jesus had to fulfill, they had to take precedence. The story of Enoch as foreshadowing the rapture is duplicative of Elijah, and Elijah is a forerunner of John the Baptist, an important thing that had to be covered. The return of Elijah was a major prophecy in Malachi and expectation of the Jews.

Thus you can make a strong point for including many other people or events from the OT to be addressed by the gospel writers. Enoch falls low on the list. For example, there are no NT direct quotes of Ecclesiastes! Perhaps the Lord felt that the Word already spoke for itself on those matters?

> The law of the Lord is perfect, refreshing the soul. The statutes of
> the Lord are trustworthy, making wise the simple. (Psalm 19:7)